# Default Thread Pool Size in MULE

Tags: mule

What are default number of threads in mule thread . For example , if i create a http connector in mule and do not specify receiver thread size , then what it maximum number of concurrent request it can handle ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default is 16.

This value and others can be found here [Mule Constant Field Values](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/constant-values.html). In particular the section for org.mule.api.config.ThreadingProfile